# how can I run PECL in my personal web site?

Tags: php

how can I run PECL in my personal web site ?

Comment: Far too vague.  Please add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean that you want to use a PECL-based extension, rather than host the repository yourself.

Google very easily finds the documentation page dedicated to [how to install a PECL extension](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php), which should contain sufficient information to get you going.  If you run into a *specific* problem, ask back about help with that particular part.

A large part of the difficulty of this is going to depend on your hosting provider.  You may find that they already have the extension installed; if they don't, following the required steps will range from easy to impossible depending on what privileges and tools you have with your account.